# Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot be empty

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a matlab code that describes the material phase you are in given the graph and function. The user inputs are temperature and composition, then the output is the material phase. The other day I had the blank function working, but now it displays the error 'Error: An array for multiple LHS assignment cannot be empty.'
If you could help me figure out how to m ake the function work again that would be great.
The script is

```
figure
y1=[320 400 500 600 700 780];
x1=[0 1 3 4 5 8];
a1c=polyfit(x1,y1,2);
y11=polyval(a1c,x1);
plot(x1,y11,'-k');
hold on
x2=[8 92];
y2=[790 790];
a2c=polyfit(x2,y2,1);
plot(x2,y2,'-k');
x3=[92 94 96 97 98 100];
y3=[780 700 600 500 400 280];
a3c=polyfit(x3,y3,2);
y3=polyval(a3c,x3);
plot(x3,y3,'-k');
x4=[8 8 7 5 2 0];
y4=[750 800 900 1000 1065 1112];
a4c=polyfit(x4,y4,2);
y4=polyval(a4c,x4);
plot(x4,y4,'-k');
x5=[0 10 20 30 40 50 60 72];
y5=[1095 1080 1000 970 910 880 815 820];
a5c=polyfit(x5,y5,1);
y5=polyval(a5c,x5);
plot(x5,y5,'-k');
x6=[72 80 90 100];
y6=[790 820 885 960];
a6c=polyfit(x6,y6,1);
plot(x6,y6,'-k');
x7=[92 92.5 97 100];
y7=[790 800 900 960];
a7c=polyfit(x7,y7,1);
plot(x7,y7,'-k');
x8=0;
y8=1200;
plot(x8,y8,'w');
xlabel('Composition(wt% Ag)')
ylabel('Temperature(Celsius)')
title('Copper-Silver Phase Diagram')
grid on
text(42,450,'{\alpha}+{\beta}')
text(17,900,'{\alpha}+L')
text(62,1000,'Liquid')
text(2,820,'{\alpha}')
text(86,835,'{\beta}+L')
text(96,780,'{\beta}')
hold off
T=input('Enter Temperature:')
C=input('Enter Composition wt% Ag:')
[ ] = copperAg( T,C )
```

The function code to call for the phase is below

```
    function [ ] = copperAg( T,C )
%UNTITLED3 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
if T>=320 && T<=780 && C>=0 && C<=8
    disp('{\alpha}')
elseif T>=790 && T<=790 && C>=8 && C<=92
    disp('{\alpha}+{\beta}')
elseif T>=780 && T<=280 && C>=92 && C<=100
    disp('{\beta}')
elseif T>=750 && T<=1112 && C>=0 && C<=8 
    disp('{\alpha}')
elseif T>=820 && T<=1095 && C>=0 && C<=72
    disp('{\alpha}+L')
elseif T>=790 && T<=960 && C>=72 && C<=100
    disp('{\beta}+L')
elseif T>=790 && T<=960 && C>=92 && C<=100
    disp('{\beta}')
else
    disp('Liquid')
end
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the `[ ]` on the final line of your script and replace with:

```
copperAg( T,C )
```